# visual studio10 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol @_RTC_CheckStackVars@8 referenced in function _wmain

Tags: visual-c++

code:

```
// displayvideo.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.

#include "stdafx.h"

#include"stdio.h"
#include "highgui.h"


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    cvNamedWindow:( "Example2", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    CvCapture* capture = cvCreateFileCapture( "tendulkar.avi" );
    IplImage* frame;
    while(1) {
        frame = cvQueryFrame( capture );
        if( !frame ) break;
        cvShowImage( "Example2", frame );
        char c = cvWaitKey(33);
        if( c == 27 ) break;
    }
    cvReleaseCapture( &capture );
    cvDestroyWindow( "Example2" );
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This function is required when you compile with [/RTCs for runtime stack checking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301374.aspx). You could turn that off in your project's C/C++ compiler options, or fix up your link-time library list so that the function can be found.

My guess is your have manually munged the list of libraries, since by default VS2010 should include the right ones for a given set of [compiler options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8wtf2dfz%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).