# LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _CrtDbgReport referenced in function _CRT_RTC_INIT SDL2

Tags: c++, linker, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to get [apitest](https://github.com/nvMcJohn/apitest) compiled..

cloned and `cmake -G "Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64" ..` as instructed, everything ok

First problem, a lot of this, I don't get even the error list:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _CrtDbgReport referenced in function _CRT_RTC_INIT
```

Gogled, and they say to switch

Project Properties -> Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Code Generation -> Runtime Library

from Multi-threaded DLL to Multi-threaded Debug DLL

Ok, I try to build again, it fails again, but at least this time I get the error list..

Again my friend:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _CrtDbgReport referenced in function _CRT_RTC_INIT   SDL2    C:\Users\GBarbieri\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\apitest\_out\thirdparty\SDL2-2.0.1\MSVCRTD.lib(_init_.obj) 1
```

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33577341/visual-studio-2015-c-and-assembly-not-building) says the project is being linked with only part of the C runtime (CRT) libary, `msvcrtd.lib`. I also need to link with the libraries `vcruntimed.lib` and `ucrtd.lib`.

Good, but how?

The apitest is a solution based on many projects, I guess I have to manually add something into the SDL2 one. I tried a lot of attempts, especially under Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies, but I never got it working

I found `msvcrtd.lib` under `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\lib` although I guess the solution is trying to build its own.

I found `vcruntimed.lib` under the same place as `msvcrtd.lib`. Instead `ucrtd.lib` is located under `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\x64`

Thanks in advance..

Ps: I have VS15 Community Edition

Comment: Do you actually need a debug build? If not, maybe you can just use an SDL version that does not reference `_CrtDbgReport` (not sure if they use  it in debug and/or release builds)?

Comment: Let's say I need it running at least, if I can get the debug better otherwise I'll try to get the maximum as I can out of the release. SDL was included.

Comment: well then check the SDL forum thread mentioned in my response:) It has a link to a precompiled SDL VS2015 version.

Comment: yeah yeah, I finally solved that problem, I inserted the two libs in the SDL project. But now I am stuck on another error.. `error C2220: warning treated as error - no 'object' file generated`

Comment: You should post all warnings then or just remove the `/WX` compiler flag that tells to treat all warnings as errors.

Comment: Yeah, I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18225636/error-c2220-warning-treated-as-error-no-object-file-generated) and did as you say, thanks Rudolfs! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to be an SDL issue. [Here](http://forums.libsdl.org/viewtopic.php?t=11533&sid=8b83c67cb812b515738af3f945687c33) is a discussion on it in the SDL forum and basically there are following solutions - adding the libraries you mentioned , taking a proper VS2015 release build (there is a link in the thread) or building SDL from sources (the thread mentions that that should work too).

Comment: Can you believe I had to clone it again and now I get different errors? `LNK2001 unresolved external symbol _RTC_CheckStackVars SDL2 C:\Users\GBarbieri\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\apitest\_out\thirdparty\SDL2-2.0.1\SDL_dxjoystick.obj`

Comment: See this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6642571/visual-studio10-error-lnk2019-unresolved-external-symbol-rtc-checkstackvars8

Answer (score 12):

in my case it was because in the runtime library option of the project I used `/MD` in debug instead of `/MDd` so it was building fine in release but not in debug

Comment: Fixed it for me!

Answer (score 8):

If you end up here because you Googled "error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __CrtDbgReport" here is a simple thing to check...

If you are comparing working DEBUG to non-working RELEASE project settings and copy/paste between them, it is easy to copy a preprocessor definition, "_DEBUG" into a RELEASE project by mistake.  I just chased my tail for two frustrating hours after a quick and sloppy cut-n-paste... see how long it takes to find it below:

```
WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN;WIN32;_CRT_NON_CONFORMING_SWPRINTFS;_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS;_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE;_DEBUG;_CONSOLE;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)
```