# Visual studio 2019 C++ compiler error on release x64 with WinToast library

Tags: c++, gcc, ide, sdl-2, unresolved-external

I use visual studio 2019 to write and compile an app in C++.In the Debug mode it works fine but in the release mode I get errors from the WinToast library:

```
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp__CrtDbgReport  {project name} {path}\wintoastlib.obj
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp__invalid_parameter  {project name} {path}\wintoastlib.obj
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp__CrtDbgReportW {project name} {path}\wintoastlib.obj
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp__calloc_dbg    {project name} {path}\Project {project name}.obj
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp__free_dbg  {project name} {path}\msvcprtd.lib(locale0_implib.obj)
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp__free_dbg  {project name} {path}\msvcprtd.lib(filesystem.obj)
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp__malloc_dbg    {project name} {path}\msvcprtd.lib(locale0_implib.obj)
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp__malloc_dbg    {project name} {path}\msvcprtd.lib(filesystem.obj)
```

I tried to put this in my preprocessor definitions:

```
WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN;WIN32;_CRT_NON_CONFORMING_SWPRINTFS;_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS;_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE;_DEBUG;_CONSOLE;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)
```

and here is a list of all libraries I use:

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <wintoastlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits.h>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
#include <filesystem>
#include <cstring>
#include <SDL_ttf.h>
#include <SDL_image.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
```

I also want to say that I import WinToast lib by inserting the header file and the .cpp file in the Header Files and Source Files. The rest of the libraries I imported by ading them to the include dir, library dir and additional dependecies.
I don't know what I did wrong. What settings I miss in the visual studio?

Edit:
It still wasn't working before I added that in my preprocessor definitions.

Comment: If I remember correctly, the `__imp` in the missing definitions says, "You'll really find me in a DLL somewhere, but where's the Lib file that describes the stub used to load it?" You show header files, but headers (mostly) only describe what's in the library for the compiler. The implementation is (usually) in a separate library file you need to specify to the linker. You do not show how you set up the linker.

Comment: Looking closer at the libraries missing, those are special debug libraries. Not sure how to turn them on, but [LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _CrtDbgReport referenced in function _CRT_RTC_INIT SDL2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35793622/4581301) (found by googling "unresolved external symbol __imp__CrtDbgReport") looks like it offers some posibilities.

Comment: `_DEBUG` in the preprocessor list defintions is for debug version,  **it must be  `NDEBUG` for the release version**.

Comment: There should be different `.lib` files and `.dlls` for Release and Debug. If you used the same ones that is an issue.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So i find out thanks to the comments that i have the _DEBUG option in the preprocessor definitions:

```
WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN;WIN32;_CRT_NON_CONFORMING_SWPRINTFS;_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS;_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE;**_DEBUG**;_CONSOLE;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)
```

I replaced it with _NDEBUG and it is working again:

```
WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN;WIN32;_CRT_NON_CONFORMING_SWPRINTFS;_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS;_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE;_NDEBUG;_CONSOLE;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)
```

Thank you all !!!